# What are the some popular tools for managing mongodb on OSX?

Tags: macos, mongodb

I'm looking for something nicer than the shell for managing mongodb on osx. What are some of the more popular options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [MongoHub](http://mongohub.todayclose.com/) is probably the prettiest

[image: MongoHub Screenshot]

- [RockMongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo) is as close as it gets to phpMyAdmin for Mongo, as far as I'm aware.

[image: RockMongo Screenshot]

The Mongo documentation lists a great many alternatives: [Mongo Documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs).

Comment: I liked MongoHub at first, but it crashes really badly all the time. I have yet to find anything better though

Comment: I'd probably stick with RockMongo, as it will be available to you regardless of your platform, unlike a native tool.